# How to copy big files from one server to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to copy 15 .bak files, each 115-120GB. My copy process is going to be from a production server. How can I do this with Robocopy? or How can I do this with Power shell?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all of figuring this out on your own? Why on earth do you want to use PowerShell for it?

Comment: If this is a one time copy, just copy them using xcopy and don't spend any more time thinking about it.  if you need to build a process to automate this for the future, robocopy or a powershell script may make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said which version of Windows you are using.  If you're using Server 2008 R2, for files that big, I would use XCOPY with the /J switch:

"Copies using unbuffered I/O. Recommended for very large files."

If Using 2003/2008 R1, you might want to take a copy of ESEUTIL.exe and use that with the /Y switch.

Either of these methods will let you copy the files in an unbuffered manner, thereby preventing your server from falling over due to memory or pool depletion.

I have a customer who kept taking out one of their cluster nodes when they copied large SQL DB files around (even locally).  Getting them to use eseutil has prevented further outages.

Comment: Why not `robocopy`?

Comment: Robocopy has not always had the /J option for unbuffered I/O. In fact, it still doesn't appear to be documented for Windows 2012:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: I remembered that the specification for `robocopy` is a pdf article, not that link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

OK :

```
robocopy /?
```

---

### ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

Started : Thu Mar 29 10:23:30 2012

```
          Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").
```

You will get much better advice, and learn a lot, if you try the simple things yourself and then ask questions when you're confused or get stuck.

There's little difference between copying big files, and copying little ones. Obviously the big ones take longer, and that might cause problems if you have a limited amount of time to do it in. But you didn't say that was the case. If there's details you haven't included in your question, then please edit it to include them.